# sqlalchemy update column with an expression

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update a row setting the result of an expression on a column, ex:

```
MyTable.query.filter_by(id=the_id).update({
  "my_col": "(now() at time zone 'utc')"
})
```

This code give me the following error :

```
(DataError) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "(now() at time zone 'utc')"
LINE 1: ...12bf98a-1ee9-4958-975d-ee99f87f1d4a', my_col='(now() at...
                                                             ^
 'UPDATE my_table SET my_col=%(redeemed_at)s WHERE id = %(id_1)s' {'my_col': "(now() at time zone 'utc')",
```

this should translate in sql to :

```
update my_table set my_col = (now() at time zone 'utc') where id = ?;
```

this SQL statement works when run from the console

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question : why does it not work, I added the error message...

Comment: I am going to guess that's because it's trying to use the string `"(now() at time zone 'utc')"` as the value. Try using `Text("(now() at time zone 'utc')")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax with sqlalchemy func object, as the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

#  get a sqlalchemy session
session.query(YourTable).filter_by(id=the_id).update(values={'my_col': func.utc_timestamp()}, synchronize_session=False)

session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the timestamp cannot be a string that is `"(now() at time zone 'utc')"`

You could try using the `Text()` function or `func.now()` or to get the time in UTC

`db.func.timezone('utc', db.func.now())`

**EDIT:**

You can try using `synchronize_session` as `'evaluate'` or,

Since you are only updating one row, you can just do this:

```
mytable_row_obj = MyTable.query.filter_by(id=the_id).one()
mytable_row_obj.my_col = ... What ever you want to put here ...
session.commit()
```

Comment: This gives me : "Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. "
InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.

Comment: wrapping with sqlalchemy.text gives me the same error

Comment: What happens when you use func.now and func.timezone?

Comment: func.now() gives same error ("Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. "), just to make sure, I am using func "from sqlalchemy import func"

Comment: I think it's a problem with the way you're using the `update` function. You could try setting `synchronize_session` to `'evaluate'`. But any how, `update` is a bulk operation function and since you are only working on one row, you could just query the object, and update the value through the attribute. I'll add an edit.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, updating the row object and saving it should work, but I prefer using the "now()" of the database, because it doesn't require that the clocks of the db server and app server are synchronized. In other words: I want all timestamps originating from the database.